# Заменить ключи массива значениями из другого массива

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив, ключей может быть много, но в обоих массивах их количество одинаково

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["first"]=>
    string(3) "xxx"
    ["second"]=>
    string(3) "yyy"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["first"]=>
    string(3) "kkk"
    ["second"]=>
    string(3) "zzz"
  }
}
```

И массив

```
array(2) {
  ["first"]=>
  string(5) "val_1"
  ["second"]=>
  string(5) "val_2"
}
```

Нужно получить массив

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["val_1"]=>
    string(3) "xxx"
    ["val_2"]=>
    string(3) "yyy"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["val_1"]=>
    string(3) "kkk"
    ["val_2"]=>
    string(3) "zzz"
  }
}
```

Comment: В цикле. все задачи, которые требуют перебора массива, выполняются в цикле.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = array_map(function($v) use ($keys){
                  return array_combine($keys, $v);
              }, $input);
```